# How to make links in a raw file clickable

Tags: android

I have a raw file with html content and comprising of `<a href` links. Right now I have referenced that raw file. Though the content displays, the links are not clickable. How do I make them clickable?

Below is the code for the same:

```
protected String doInBackground(final Void... params) {
        try {
            return Utils.readTextFile(Application.getAppContext(), R.raw.acknowledgements);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If using a TextView, you might use [android:autoLink](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aautoLink) in XML or [setAutoLinkMask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setAutoLinkMask%28int%29) in code to make URLs clickable. Note that this has nothing to do with <a> tags being present, it just scans for URLs (or other content such as e-mail addresses, if you enable them).

Comment: what do i set the autolink to ? I tried android:autolink = "web" gives me error